# R data.table: Random sample of rows from second table by group

Tags: r, data.table

Say we have two tables, each with a group indicator common between the two. Then for every row in DT1 we want to randomly select 2 rows from DT2 within each group.

One possible way to address this would be to randomly generate an integer column in DT2 that would coincide with the rows of DT1, and join the two tables together. But the number of rows varies by group and it's not clear how we could condition on this length by group.

Minimum working example:

```
DT1 <- data.table(var1=seq(1:20),
                  group=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4))
DT2 <- data.table(obs=seq(1:13),
                  group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5))
```

View:

```
DT1
    var1 group
 1:    1     1
 2:    2     1
 3:    3     1
 4:    4     1
 5:    5     1
 6:    6     2
 7:    7     2
 8:    8     2
 9:    9     2
10:   10     3
11:   11     3
12:   12     3
13:   13     4
14:   14     4
15:   15     4
16:   16     4
17:   17     4
18:   18     4
19:   19     4
20:   20     4

DT2
    obs group
 1:   1     1
 2:   2     1
 3:   3     1
 4:   4     2
 5:   5     2
 6:   6     2
 7:   7     3
 8:   8     3
 9:   9     3
10:  10     4
11:  11     4
12:  12     4
13:  13     5
```

So for every row in DT1, I would like to pair it with 2 randomly selected rows from DT2 by group. The expected result might look something like:

```
DT3
    var1 group obs
 1:    1     1   1
 2:    1     1   3
 3:    2     1   2
 4:    2     1   3
...
37:   19     4   10
38:   19     4   11
39:   20     4   10
40:   20     4   12
```

In case it needs to be said, the actual application has 400 million rows in DT1 and 10 million in DT2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A direct translation of your needs is:

```
DT2[DT1, on=.(group), allow.cartesian=TRUE, .(var1, obs=obs[sample(.N, 2L)]), by=.EACHI]
```

This might be faster:

```
gn <- DT1[, .(nsamp=2*.N), keyby=.(group)]
DT2[gn, on=.(group), .(obs=obs[sample(.N, nsamp, replace=TRUE)]), by=.EACHI][,
    var1 := rep(DT1$var1, each=2L)]
```

data:

```
set.seed(0L)
library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(var1=101:120, group=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4))
DT2 <- data.table(obs=201:213, group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5))
```

sample output:

```
    group var1 obs
 1:     1  101 203
 2:     1  101 201
 3:     1  102 202
 4:     1  102 203
 5:     1  103 203
 6:     1  103 201
 7:     1  104 203
 8:     1  104 202
 9:     1  105 202
10:     1  105 203
11:     2  106 204
12:     2  106 206
13:     2  107 204
14:     2  107 205
15:     2  108 205
16:     2  108 206
17:     2  109 205
18:     2  109 206
19:     3  110 209
20:     3  110 207
21:     3  111 209
22:     3  111 208
23:     3  112 207
24:     3  112 208
25:     4  113 210
26:     4  113 212
27:     4  114 211
28:     4  114 210
29:     4  115 211
30:     4  115 212
31:     4  116 211
32:     4  116 210
33:     4  117 211
34:     4  117 210
35:     4  118 210
36:     4  118 211
37:     4  119 212
38:     4  119 211
39:     4  120 210
40:     4  120 211
    group var1 obs
```

Comment: As always, you nailed it. The one-liner with `allow.cartesian` is great, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using `dplyr`, I am sure this can be translated to `data.table` as well. The logic being we first calculate number of rows for each group in `DT1`, `left_join` them to `DT2` by `group` and use `sample` to select randomly `n * 2` rows in each `group`.

```
library(dplyr)

DT1 %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(n = n()) %>%
   left_join(DT2, by = "group") %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   slice(sample(seq_len(n()), first(n) * 2, replace = TRUE)) %>%
   select(-n)

#    var1 group   obs
#   <int> <dbl> <int>
# 1     4     1     1
# 2     3     1     3
# 3     4     1     2
# 4     4     1     1
# 5     2     1     3
# 6     3     1     2
# 7     1     1     1
# 8     4     1     2
# 9     4     1     2
#10     3     1     2
# … with 30 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah. A `dplyr` solution would be fine, one thing that isn't clear from this though is if the original row from DT1 is retained? (the column `var1` would be the identifier here...). It seems that we are simply joining and then randomly sampling, which might not guarantee the original row from DT1 was retained in the final result?

Comment: @BryanMichael If you want `var1` in final output you might need `mutate` then. See updated answer. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: not quite... if you add `%>% arrange(var1)` it might be more clear what the issue is. There should only be 2 of every `var1` in the result. You certainly are on the right track, I'll play around with this and see if I can't get it working. I'll add what the fix is once I figure it out, and then accept your answer. Thanks!!

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question then. In my attempt, there are no rows from `DT1`, all the rows are from `DT2` also there is no condition on `var1` at all and if what you are saying is true then shouldn't your expected output have 60 rows then to have `3 of every var1 in the result.` ?

Comment: You are correct, I was not very clear on what the expected result was, sorry! The expected result I posted was only the two samples from DT2, which would be 40 rows, and the final join with DT1 would in fact be 60. 

That being said, @chinsoon12's answer below is true to `data.table` and is exactly what I was going for. I think your `dplyr` solution is close. I'll work through the rest with it and share in case someone else prefers `dplyr`.